# Bibliography isn't displayed

Tags: bibliographies, packages, miktex, texstudio, biber

So I'm using Latex for the first time everything seems to work, except the citation and \printbibliography. The text in brackets is the cite ID [amsldoc02] not the number [1] and it is bold.
I have looked for the problem for some time now and tried different things but I don't seem to find anything that works. My code looks like this right now.

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[paper=a4,oneside,fontsize=11pt,headsepline,toc=bibliography,toc=listof,titlepage=true,DIV=15,BCOR=15mm]{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{exscale}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\graphicspath{{images/}}
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}

\begin{document}

    \frontmatter

        \include{sections/titlepage}
        \include{sections/kurzfassung}
        \include{sections/abstract}
        \include{sections/erklaerung}
        \include{sections/danksagung}
        \tableofcontents
        \listoffigures
        \listoftables

    \mainmatter

        \include{sections/einleitung}
        \include{sections/grundlagen}
        \include{sections/konzept}
        \include{sections/modell}
        \include{sections/konstruktion}
        \printbibliography

    \appendix

        \include{sections/anhang_a}

\end{document}
```

The .bib file looks like this

```
@manual{amsldoc02,
    author={{American Mathematical Society}},
    title={User's Guide for the amsmath Package},
    year={2002},
    month={2},
    version={2.0},
    url={ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf},
}
```

Also I don't know if there is anything wrong with the whole code. Packages, order, etc.

I'd really appreciate the help!

Comment: Have you checked [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/106162)

Comment: Welcome! You need to run `biber` and then recompile. (See link in comment above.) Your packages are loaded in the wrong order. `cleveref` should probably be last. `hyperref` should be last-but-one.

Comment: If you need further help, please make a minimal working example we can compile to reproduce the problem.

Comment: what editor are you using?

Comment: If you are using an editor to start the compilation for you, see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Answer (score 1):

try to run like following:

```
pdflatex
biber
pdflatex
pdflatex
```

then view pdf

also keep in mind, you need to cite in the body, only cited documents will show in the bibliography.
I added

```
it need some citation from bib \cite{amsldoc02}.
```

before `\printbibliography`